# Thymeleaf html file can't find Controller class object

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Spring in Action(6th edition), while designing view html file cannot find object of controller class, html file shows 32 mistakes, the reason is it cannot resolve it.

I have added thymeleaf configuration and class path is correct, what is the reason of this mistake or did someone experience this type of mistake?

2023-03-10T21:28:22.305+06:00 ERROR 16760 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "design": Error resolving template [design], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Keywords: taco, wrap, id, ingredient are underlined with red.

HTML FILE:

```
<h1>Design your taco!</h1>
<form method="POST" th:object="${taco}">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="wraps">
            <h3>Designate your wrap:</h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${wrap}">
                <input th:field="*{ingredients}" type="checkbox"
                       th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ingredient-group" id="proteins">
            <h3>Pick your protein:</h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${protein}">
                <input th:field="*{ingredients}" type="checkbox"
                       th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ingredient-group" id="cheeses">
            <h3>Choose your cheese:</h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${cheese}">
                <input th:field="*{ingredients}" type="checkbox"
                       th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ingredient-group" id="veggies">
            <h3>Determine your veggies:</h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${veggies}">
                <input th:field="*{ingredients}" type="checkbox"
                       th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ingredient-group" id="sauces">
            <h3>Select your sauce:</h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${sauce}">
                <input th:field="*{ingredients}" type="checkbox"
                       th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
```

DESIGN CONTROLLER CLASS:

```
package com.example.demo.web;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import com.example.demo.Ingredient;
import com.example.demo.Ingredient.Type;
import com.example.demo.Taco;
import com.example.demo.TacoOrder;

@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
@SessionAttributes("tacoOrder")

public class DesignController {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model) {
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
                new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
                new Ingredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
                new Ingredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN),
                new Ingredient("CARN", "Carnitas", Type.PROTEIN),
                new Ingredient("TMTO", "Diced Tomatoes", Type.VEGGIES),
                new Ingredient("LETC", "Lettuce", Type.VEGGIES),
                new Ingredient("CHED", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE),
                new Ingredient("JACK", "Monterrey Jack", Type.CHEESE),
                new Ingredient("SLSA", "Salsa", Type.SAUCE),
                new Ingredient("SRCR", "Sour Cream", Type.SAUCE)
        );

        Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for (Type type : types) {
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(), filterByType(ingredients, type));


        }

    }

    @ModelAttribute(name = "tacoOrder")
    public TacoOrder order() {
        return new TacoOrder();
    }

    @ModelAttribute(name = "taco")
    public Taco taco() {
        return new Taco();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm() {
        return "design";
    }

    private Iterable<Ingredient> filterByType(
            List<Ingredient> ingredients, Type type) {
        return ingredients
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(type))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Comment: "_did someone experience this type of mistake?_" - Yes - many people did. Have you researched similar ["error resolving template"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error+resolving+template+site%3Astackoverflow.com) questions? What were your findings?

Comment: Just a side note: Regarding sections of the HTML which are underlined in red: This is not necessarily a problem. Content such as `th:object="${taco}"` is not standard HTML, and therefore can cause your editor to complain - even though it is completely valid as a Thymeleaf template.  You can (a) ignore such Thymeleaf-related warnings; or (b) use the HTML5-valid attribute syntax ``data-th-object="${taco}"`` instead.

Comment: Regarding my second comment: I forgot the most obvious point: Does your Thymeleaf template contain the following: `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`? That "_prevents our IDE from complaining about the lack of a namespace definition for all those th:* attributes._" ([ref.](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#a-multi-language-welcome))

Comment: Yes, tried them didn't find that works for me yet, in many cases there was mistake s with class path initialization. Data-th-object solves the mistake, but there is still mistake in server. <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> of course, I did.

Comment: I have this mistake in run time: <2023-03-11T18:47:14.950+06:00 ERROR 19382 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")] with root cause>, which indicates that there's problem with parsing index.html file.

Comment: That error is different from the error mentioned in the question. Show us the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: I apologize for confusion, application runs successfully, but when I go to `http://localhost:8080/design` it throws me error, which I shared as answer below (too much characters), in the meantime, IntelliJ IDE runtime environment throws another error (shown as answer)